# How can I reconstruct a 3D volume from its skeletonization?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d

I have a multidimensional blob and the result of its skeletonization. 
I have pruned some branches from the skeleton and now I want to reconstruct the multidimensional blob without the areas representing the branches I have pruned. 
I was wondering if there is a function similar to pymorph.cthick which "creates the binary image y by performing a thickening of the binary image f conditioned to the binary image g" [https://pythonhosted.org/pymorph] but that can be used in multidimensional arrays instead. 
Or if there is any perspective or approach that you could suggest to reconstruct the original volume without the areas representing the branches I have pruned in the skeleton.

Thanks in advance!  [image: The grey area is the original volume and the blue is the resulting skeletonization, I have pointed with red arrows to branches I have pruned in the skeleton, just as an example.]

Comment: https://imagej.net/MorphoLibJ

Comment: http://dream3d.bluequartz.net/binaries/Help/DREAM3D/Filters/ITKImageProcessingFilters/ITKBinaryErodeImage/index.html